# $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(1+t)^{1/2} - (1-t)^{1/2}}{t}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find the limit of this?

Should I use the conjugate pair?

It doesn't seem logical that this has a limit, I started by trying to simplifying the function but I don't think you can simplify this any further.
$$
    \lim_{t\to 0}   \frac{(1+t)^{1/2} - (1-t)^{1/2}}{t}
$$

Comment: thank you thomas. i need to fix the (1-t) it should be (1-t)^1/2 as well

Comment: You can use LaTeX (MathJax) to format your question. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for more on this.

Comment: Yes, multiplying by the conjugate is a good idea. And it works.

Comment: Have you learned derivatives?

Comment: @Miguel: Does it look right now?

Comment: @thomas yes it does and thanks for the tip i will used the site you published in the future.

Comment: @jonas no i have not im still in my second week of class but im stumped on this one.

Comment: @ experimentx you are right it t-> 0

Comment: @Miguel: Just asking because rewriting it as $\frac{(1+t)^{1/2}-1}{t}-\frac{(1-t)^{1/2}-1}{t}$ would be a way to quickly see what the limit is if you already know enough about derivatives.  Regardless, maybe you'll find these two limits a little easier than the original.

Comment: looks like you are in right direction, use conjugate pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (as mentioned in the comments). By multiplying by the *conjugate* you get
$$
\frac{[(1+t)^{1/2} - (1-t)^{1/2}]}{t}\cdot\frac{[(1+t)^{1/2} + (1-t)^{1/2}]}{[(1+t)^{1/2} + (1-t)^{1/2}]} = \frac{1+t - (1-t)}{t[(1+t)^{1/2} + (1-t)^{1/2}]}
$$

Now try to simplify this expression a bit and then look at $t\to 0$ again.

Comment: thank you thomas on both count  for teaching me how to properly put my math values into this forums, fixing my question, and on top of that proposing answer im forever in your debt. Thank you.

Comment: @Miguel: I am glad to help.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{t\to 0}   \frac{\sqrt{1+t} - \sqrt{1-t}}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}   \frac{\left(\sqrt{1+t} - \sqrt{1-t}\right)\left(\sqrt{1+t} + \sqrt{1-t}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1+t} + \sqrt{1-t}\right)t}= \\
=\lim_{t\to 0}   \frac{{1+t} - {(1-t)}}{\left(\sqrt{1+t} + \sqrt{1-t}\right)t}=\lim_{t\to 0}   \frac{2t}{\left(\sqrt{1+t} + \sqrt{1-t}\right)t} = \\ 
=\lim_{t\to 0}   \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+t} + \sqrt{1-t}}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
    \lim_{t\to 0}   \frac{(1+t)^{1/2} - (1-t)^{1/2}}{t} 
= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{((1+t)^{1/2} - (1 - t)^{1/2})((1+t)^{1/2}+(1-t)^{1/2})}{t((1+t)^{1/2} + (1-t)^{1/2})} 
$$
$$= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1 + t - (1 - t)}{t((1+t)^{1/2} + (1-t)^{1/2})} =\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2t}{t((1+t)^{1/2} + (1-t)^{1/2})} $$

$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2}{((1+t)^{1/2} + (1-t)^{1/2})} = \frac{2}{2} = 1 $$